# Unable to mock Configuration.Formatters using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mocking, moq, mediatypeformatter

I am developing an ASP.NET web API application. I am unit testing to every component in my application. I am using Moq Unit Test framework to mock the data. Now I am trying to mock the `Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter` in my Unit test because my action under unit test is using it as follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Register(model)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                Content = new ObjectContent<List<string>>(errors, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter)
            };
}
```

I am trying to mock the `Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter` in the Unit Test as follow.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Register_ReturnErrorsWithBadRequest_IfValidationFails()
{
    PostUserRegistration model = new PostUserRegistration {
        Name = "Wai Yan Hein",
        Email = "waiyanhein@gmail.com",
        Password = ""
    };

    Mock<JsonMediaTypeFormatter> formatterMock = new Mock<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>();
    Mock<MediaTypeFormatterCollection> formatterCollection = new Mock<MediaTypeFormatterCollection>();
    formatterCollection.Setup(x => x.JsonFormatter).Returns(formatterMock.Object);
    Mock<HttpConfiguration> httpConfigMock = new Mock<HttpConfiguration>();
    httpConfigMock.Setup(x => x.Formatters).Returns(formatterCollection.Object);
    Mock<IAccountRepo> accRepoMock = new Mock<IAccountRepo>();

    AccountsController controller = new AccountsController(accRepoMock.Object);

    controller.Configuration = httpConfigMock.Object;
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Faking some model error");
    HttpResponseMessage response = controller.Register(model);
    Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

When I run my unit tests, it is giving me this error.
[image]

> System.NotSupportedException: Invalid setup on a non-virtual
> (overridable in VB) member: x => x.JsonFormatter

So, how can I fix that error and how can I mock `Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter`?

Comment: Everything would be much easier if you return `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors)` from the action. In this case you don't even need to mock `JsonFormatter`. Another problem with your code is that you couple your API to JSON format. What about XML or other possible formats?

Comment: Ok. I’ll try to use this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to test that the framework is doing what it was designed to do. Instead, similar to what was suggested before in comments, I suggest using the built in methods of the `ApiController` and also refactoring the action to the syntax suggested from documentation for that version of Asp.Net Web API

```
public IHttpActionResult Register(PostUserRegistration model) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState); //<-- will extract errors from model state

    //...code removed for brevity

    return Ok();
}
```

A simple example of a unit test for the above method could look something like this...

```
[TestMethod]
public void Register_ReturnErrorsWithBadRequest_IfValidationFails() {            
    //Arrange
    PostUserRegistration model = new PostUserRegistration {
        Name = "Wai Yan Hein",
        Email = "waiyanhein@gmail.com",
        Password = ""
    };

    var accRepoMock = new Mock<IAccountRepo>();
    var controller = new AccountsController(accRepoMock.Object);
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Faking some model error");

    //Act
    var response = controller.Register(model) as InvalidModelStateResult; //<-- Note the cast here

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
}
```

If the injected dependency is not going to be referenced/invoked in the method under test you could also forego the mock and inject `null`. That however is dependent on code not provided in the original question.